# How to enable wildcard file paths for git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

I would expect `git diff` to work like `git add` and others, in being able to do something like

```
git diff **/models.py
```

rather than having to do

```
git diff /full/path/to/my/python/file/called/models.py
```

It's strange though because

```
git commit **/models.py
git add **/models.py
```

both work as you'd expect.

Comment: Make sure you are running git diff from the root of the repository (or alternately, that your path spec is relative to the working folder).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
```

Example

```
git diff -- */models.py
```

http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html

Comment: Is there a name for that double dash?

Comment: From the man. 

`$ git diff HEAD -- ./test`
Compare with the tip of the current branch, but limit the comparison to the file "test".